# Managing multiple requests of a product at same time in WCF service

Tags: wcf

In an eCommerce application, two users read that an amount of 'n' is left of a particular product say A. Now both users try to purchase 'n'-amount of product A and hit say purchase button. Now getting product amount information and purchasing are done using a WCF service. How can we manage this kind of situation in a WCF service where 2 users or more try to purchase same amount of a product?